# python directory recursive traversal program

Tags: python, recursion, directory

my program does not believe that folders are directory, assuming theyre files, and because of this, the recursion prints the folders as files, then since there are no folders waiting to be traversed through, the program finishes.

```
import os
import sys
class DRT:
    def dirTrav(self, dir, buff):
        newdir = []
        for file in os.listdir(dir):
            print(file)
            if(os.path.isdir(file)):
                newdir.append(os.path.join(dir, file))
        for f in newdir:
            print("dir: " + f)
            self.dirTrav(f, "")
dr = DRT()
dr.dirTrav(".", "")
```

Comment: I just tested it on ubuntu 12.04 with python 2.7 and it worked. Not sure why its not for you.

Comment: @placeybordeaux im on os x... could this be a problem?

Comment: As a side note: Don't put parentheses around `if` conditions and the like in Python; it's jarring and draws the attention to "Is he doing something complex here that needs parentheses?" instead of the actual condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not checking the right thing. `file` is just the filename, not the pathname. That's why you need `os.path.join(dir, file)`, on the next line, right? So you need it in the `isdir` call, too. But you're just passing `file`.

So, instead of asking "is `.foo/bar/baz` a directory?" you're just asking "is `baz` a directory?" It interprets just `baz` as `./baz`, as you'd expect. And, since there (probably) is no "`./baz`", you get back False.

So, change this:

```
if(os.path.isdir(file)):
    newdir.append(os.path.join(dir, file))
```

to:

```
path = os.path.join(dir, file)
if os.path.isdir(path):
    newdir.append(path)
```

All that being said, using `os.walk` as sotapme suggested is simpler than trying to build it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

See [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) from there:

*This example displays the number of bytes taken by non-directory files in each directory under the starting directory, except that it doesn’t look under any CVS subdirectory:*

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I was unaware of os walk, but it seems quite simple to implement.